# Print "\n" into file using bash

Tags: bash, escaping, special-characters

I want to print this string:

```
.asciz "%d\n"
```

into a file.
When i try now it says:

```
.asciz "0\n"
```

it seems like it interpretes the %d as 0.

Now i write `echo ".asciz "\""%d\\\n"\""`

Comment: Cannot reproduce, although the line you show has mismatched unquoted `"`. The simpler `echo ".asciz \"%d\n\""` should work fine, though (although the single-quote solution given by Ruslan Osmanov is better).

Comment: The only thing that would interpret `%d` as `0` is `printf` if the corresponding argument is missing.

Answer (score 1):

On modern GNU/Linux systems, inside a single-quoted string nothing is interpreted, and you can simply run the following:

```
echo '.asciz "%d\n"' > file
```

The single quotes within should be escaped, however:

```
echo '13'\'''
# outputs 13'
```

But [there are exceptions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). For example, if you put `echo '1\n2'` into `some-script.sh` file and call it with modified `BASHOPTS` environment variable, the command may replace `\n` with the newline character:

```
$ env BASHOPTS=xpg_echo bash some-script.sh
1
2
```

So, strictly speaking, `echo` is unsafe. Alternatively, you can invoke `printf`:

```
printf '%s' '.asciz "%d\n"'
```

Or the built-in version:

```
builtin printf '%s' '.asciz "%d\n"'
```

(see `info bash printf`).

Comment: i have tried this, it gets me a newline in the file

Comment: Im new to scripting so i was not expecting anything advanced. I wrote the desired text into a file and then did echo instead, echo file1 >> file2, something like that, thanks anyways!